# russian language not properly coming in android

Tags: android

I have a file with data that contain values in english and russian.
But when I try to print russian data in logcat, its not shown in the way its there in the file. Its coming as some special characters. What may be the reason?

For the above question, below answer worked....

Added new thing to the question:

I have search functionality in my app. So when I search this russian data, its not showing any results..if the data is english, it works perfectly...What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for the second part too.. The problem was that word stored in db is actually russian only. Though it was seeming like english letters, in real case, it was in russian. I installed `Russian Keyboard (GameWarrior)` from market. Using that keyboard, I typed the search string. Then it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the support @Mudassir.

Answer (score 3):

As I experienced, old ADT's Logcat doesn't support languages other than English. Update you ADT plugin (hope you are using Eclipse). I was also facing the same problem with Japanese, but as I've the new ADT now, its fine. You can update the ADT from Eclipse's **Help** menu >> **Check for Updates**.

Comment: Hey it worked...Thanks..I have one more doubt. I have search functionality in my app. So when I search this russian data, its not showing any results..if the data is english, it works perfectly...What could be the reason?

Comment: I hop, you are using SQLite database. Lets perform a test, copy a value from the database, then search this through your app, then let me know about the results.

Comment: ya i have db..actually some columns contain english and russian words...suppose i have a field with data "sample *" where * refers to some russian word. If I give a search as "sample" then this data is not displayed in searched results...What could be the reason?

Comment: This may the issue of SQL query. Change it to `% searchString %` and then try again.

Comment: no...i have kept those values into a list..i am searching in that list only...from that list only I printed in logcat...

Comment: String name = obj.getName();
if(name.toLowerCase().contains(searchKey.toLowerCase()) {
   list.add(obj);
} This list should contain my result...